# Can't find does not contain element in array in mongodb?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I am a beginner in mongodb. I want to check if a particular element is present in array. If the given  element is already present in the array it should show  **already exists**. If the given element is not present in array it should show **this array doesn't contain this element**. But my program it shows **already exist** for all input. What is the problem in my code?

```html
var mongodb=require("mongodb");
var mongoclient=mongodb.MongoClient;
var url="mongodb://localhost:27017/hello";
mongoclient.connect(url,function(err,db)
{
    if(err)
    {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("connect the details database successfully");
        var collection=db.collection("users");
        collection.find({"email":{$contains:"sample@gmail.com"}},function(error,ok)
        {
          if(error)
          {
              console.log(error);
          }
          else if(ok)
          {
              console.log("already exist");
          }
          // print something if element is not present in array how can i check?
        });
        db.close();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html):

> Anywhere a callback is passed to a query in Mongoose, the callback
>   follows the pattern callback(error, results). What results is depends
>   on the operation: For findOne() it is a potentially-null single
>   document, **find() a list of documents**, count() the number of documents,
>   update() the number of documents affected, etc. The API docs for
>   Models provide more detail on what is passed to the callbacks.

So, you will always get a list of documents which, however, can be empty.